# External access to dualstack Kuberentes service with public ipv6 ip without load balancer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, ipv6

I've created a dual-stack GKE cluster in Google Cloud, deployed a sample Nginx deployment and service with RequireDualStack, and created a firewall rule to allow all IPv6 traffic `::0/0` to everything.

Nodes/Pods IP range: `2600:1900:0:1::/64` (Public/Primary Range)

Service IPs range: `2600:2D00:0:4::0:0/64` (Google private address range).

How to assign service ip from primary range instead of Google private address range, so that it can be connected from public network without using LoadBalancer/Ingress/Gateway/NodePort?

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde updated question to reflect the invalid statement, updated details from https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips#architecture

Answer (score 0):

**Try below troubleshooting steps to access the service outside the cluster which may help to resolve your issue :**

- Ensure that the Cluster runs `GKE version 1.28` and above (GA). `1.26+ GKE` contains only the Preview Version of L4 DualStack, which does not include IPv6 Static IPs, Standard Tier Networking, Custom IPv6 Subnets.
- Know that the IPv6 is not supported as single-stack IPv6 for Pods or nodes.

- Note: For nodeport services, You are capable of sending requests to the GKE Service either using the ClusterIP address (internally) and the port field or the Nodes IP address (externally) and the nodePort field. Each Node external IP address can be used to access the Service.

- Check if the firewall rule is correctly configured by using below command:

  `gcloud alpha compute firewall-rules describe <firewall name\>`

  Note the source range is the same as the subnetIpv6CidrBlock. The target tags are the tags on the GKE nodes
- Verify that a node has been correctly assigned an IPv6 address, verify whether a node has been correctly assigned IPv6 addresses for pods using below commands:

  `kubectl get nodes <node-name\> -o go-template --template='{{range .status.addresses}}{{printf "%s: %s\\n" .type .address}}{{end}}'`

  `kubectl get nodes <node-name\> -o go-template --template='{{range .spec.podCIDRs}}{{printf "%s\\n" .}}{{end}}'`

If the above steps do not resolve your issue try using [service type loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dual-stack/#service-type-loadbalancer).

Attaching a troubleshooting [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#verify) for reference.

Comment: pods and nodes IPs are assigned from subnetIpv6CidrBlock and able to connect from public network

but service IPs are assigned from servicesIpv6CidrBlock and unable to connect from public network

GKE version is 1.27.6-gke.1506000

Comment: Can you confirm that you are accessing by using `NODE\_IP\_ADDRESS:NODE\_PORT`. You could use a Load Balancer to forward traffic per [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer) or deploy a [GKE Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) to expose the service as NodePort where  GKE ingress provides you with a L7 LB and [provides container native load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#container-native_load_balancing).

Comment: using load balancer, or pod ip, or node port is not the problem statement, they are working absolutely fine, my requirement is to access application from service ipv6 directely from public network

Comment: Dual-stack networking with GKE has the following [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips#dual_stack_network). Can you verify those and let me know that every point is satisfied.

Comment: thanks for link, as per architecture GCP reserved 2600:2D00:0:4::0:0/64 range for google private address range, I have to correct the question about service IP range, but is there any way to reserve service ip from primary range?